# Why take first index value this code?

Tags: jquery, ajax

**I want to use ajax by taking the id and task id from the array**

[please can try](https://jsfiddle.net/azizhudaikaratas/hvnjnm6o/1/)

*Save to the database in each click, but I could not
convert the id to json data here*

```
 function add()
    {
            var selectId = $("#pickData");
            var selected = new Array();
            var objResult = [];
 selected = selectId.find(" :selected").toArray();
```

> ---
>
> recurrent code block

```
var seciliDizin = selectId.find(" :selected");
            seciliDizin.each(function () {
                objResult.push({
                    userId: seciliDizin.data('id'), 
                    taskId: seciliDizin.data('tid')
                });
            });
```

> ---

```
            console.log(selected);
            console.log(objResult);
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: '@Url.Action("AppointToAddResult", "GorevIslemleri")',

             //   data: { tid: taskId, : id, : userId },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (list) {
                    debugger;
                    if (list.taskId !== 0 && list.ıserId !== 0) {
                        // document.getElementById('taskEditModal').reset();
                        //$("#warningModal .modal-body").html("<p>Kayıt Yapıldı</p>");
                        // $("#warningModal").modal();
                        // $("#taskEditModal").modal("hide");
                    }
                }
            });


        }
```

> tried but not worked  `selectId.find("option :selected");`

[image: not getting the next index]

Comment: can u summarize ur issues/problems in point form?

Comment: from ur fiddle, you are having an issue in function `this.getValues` is this the only issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[addBtn click](https://jsfiddle.net/azizhudaikaratas/hvnjnm6o/4/)

```
 $("#pAdd").on('click', function() {
        var p = pickThis.find("#pickData option:selected");
         var objResult = [];
            p.each(function () {
                objResult.push({
                    taskId: $(this).data('tid'),
                    userId: $(this).data('id')

                });
                });
        console.log(objResult);
        p.clone().appendTo("#pickListResult");
        p.remove();
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/hvnjnm6o/3/

- Use `$(this)` instead of `this` inside `each` to get the data
- and `text()` instead of `text`

**Code**

```
  this.getValues = function() {
    var objResult = [];

    this.find("#pickListResult option").each(function() {
      // console.log("getValues", this);
      objResult.push({
        id: $(this).data("id"),
        tid: $(this).data("tid"),
        text: $(this).text()
      });
    });

    return objResult;

 };
```

Comment: getValue only brings the objects of the selected table. I will click on the buttons I want and give these values ​​to the database when I select them 
            >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>var selected = new Array();
          
$("#pickData").find(" :selected").toArray();  my request brings the whole code. can we get the id's here?